# Spyder IDE not freeing DLL resources?

Tags: python, c++, spyder

I am developing a Python program (using Spyder) that uses `C++` for some computations. I put the corresponding `C++`-methods in a `.dll`, compiled it, embedded it with `ctypes`, ran the Python script with Spyder - everything works fine. But when I need to recompile the `.dll` because of some changes in the source code, the compiler exits with an error (MSVS 2013), saying

```
fatal error LNK1168: cannot open C:\path_to_dll\myLib.dll for writing
```

This leads me to believe that Spyder still somehow has access on the file (although script execution is over) since the problem disappears when I close Spyder. How can I fix this? It's really anoying to always have to close Spyder for some minor changes in the `.dll`! I already tried closing the `iPython`-Console, as suggested in some other threads, as well as closing the `.py`-File I am working on, but the problem persists.

Any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: Did you try to restart the console kernel instead of closing Spyder? You can do that by pressing `Ctrl+.` while the focus is in the console.

Comment: This did the trick, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As rightly pointed out by Carlos Cordoba, closing the Spyder kernel solved the problem!